# ValueError - Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'add' caused by Django URLs

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Here is my urls.py code,

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'stories'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<pk>', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
  #  path('<story_id>/ratings', views.rating, name='rating'),
    path('add', views.CreateStory.as_view(), name='add-story'),
]
```

I get above error when click the link,

```
 <li><a href="{% url 'stories:add-story' %}">Click me</a></li>
```

And my views.py file includes following,

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Story

class CreateStory(CreateView):
    model = Story
    fields = [' story_title', 'story_content', 'story_rating']
```

Comment: Post the full traceback and the code for `CreateStory`.

Comment: Looks like the error is in your views.py

Comment: @Håken Lid See my edited question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL `/add/` is being handled by the detail view, and gives a `ValueError` because `add` is not an integer primary key.

There are two things you can change, either should fix the problem.

Firstly, move the `add-story` URL pattern above `detail` so that `/add/` is matched by the `add-story` URL pattern first.

Secondly, change the group to `<int:pk>` to tell Django that `pk` should be an integer, so that it doesn't match strings like `'add'`.

```
path('add', views.CreateStory.as_view(), name='add-story'),
path('<int:pk>', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```